# How do I access service account details from main account [google]?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-developers-console

Context:

I have a service account that updates a Google Sheet on a daily basis and I want to add functionalities to the Sheet by extending it with Apps Script. I developed the script with my own personal account (same I used to create the service account) and it seems I can't access the service-account information when it's making changes to the Spreadsheet. What I mean is that I set up a trigger for changes on the spreadsheet but when I try to verify who made the changes I get a blank string.
Quoting [the docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user):

> The circumstances in which the email address is available vary: for example, the user's email address is not available in any context that allows a script to run without that user's authorization, like a simple onOpen(e) or onEdit(e) trigger, a custom function in Google Sheets

How do I fix this? Is there a different design I should use?

Comment: 1. In your situation, who is the owner of the Spreadsheet? Which is your account or the service account? 2. When your Spreadsheet is edited by the service account, what language are you using? I thought that from these points, when the Spreadsheet is edited by the service account, it might be able to be detected. But, if I misunderstood your current situation, I apologize.

Comment: The owner is my account, the service account is using Google Sheet APIs to make changes

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood the owner of Spreadsheet and the method for exiting Spreadsheet using the service account. Here, I would like to confirm your expected goal. In your goal, you want to know whether the service account edited the Spreadsheet using Sheets API when the Spreadsheet is edited. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, you described exactly what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, is this workaround useful? https://tanaikech.github.io/2022/11/10/workaround-detecting-to-edit-google-spreadsheet-using-sheets-api-with-service-account/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service accounts are not real users, this can be noted in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#differences_between_a_service_account_and_a_user_account). Please note the following:

> Service accounts do not belong to your Google Workspace domain, unlike user accounts. If you share Google Workspace assets, like docs or events, with your entire Google Workspace domain, they are not shared with service accounts. Similarly, Google Workspace assets created by a service account are not created in your Google Workspace domain. As a result, your Google Workspace and Cloud Identity admins can't own or manage these assets.

> Service accounts do not have passwords, and cannot log in via browsers or cookies.

The triggers that are setup on your script would require them to be logged in to the browser in order to capture the email address, a service account can't do that so that would be the reason why you are unable to gather this information.

Comment: the problem is that even if a regular user that has access to the document makes some changes, I'm still not able to see his email from the script.

Comment: If the user has not provided consent it will not be possible to retrieve the information, if you are using an installable trigger, this trigger runs based on your account. It cannot retrieve the email of the other user as the one that provided consent is your account. I would suggest checking the documentation that you have referenced again.